# Distance is NULL value when mathematically distance is calculated from latitude & longitude

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

one is trips, the other one is items....

Here's a tuple from the items table:

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  id  |  item_desc    |   sending_from_latitude  |   sending_from_longitude   |  sending_to_latitude   |  sending_to_longitude    |   from_date  |  to_date   |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1   |  Toy Gun      |        15.2993265        |      74.12399599999999     |       10.8505159       |         76.2710833       | 2016-07-27   | 2016-07-30 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Now, here is a tuple for the trips table:

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  id  |  trip_desc    |   travelling_from_latitude |   travelling_from_longitude   |  travelling_to_latitude   |  travelling_to_longitude  |   from_date  |  to_date   |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1   |  Bombay 2 Goa |        15.2993265          |      74.12399599999999        |       10.8505159          |         76.2710833        | 2016-07-27   | 2016-07-30 |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

### What I want to do?

There is a web application which will get the **sending_from_latitude**, **sending_from_longitude**, **sending_to_latitude**, **sending_to_longitude** from the item.

Then it will select all the trips whose:

1. `travelling_from_latitude` will match `sending_from_latitude`.
2. `travelling_from_longitude` will match `sending_from_longitude`.
3. `travelling_to_latititude` will match `sending_to_latitude`.
4. `travelling_to_longitude` will match `sending_to_longitude`.

So I have written a function:

```
function getTripListMatchingItem($Flat,$Flon,$Tlat,$Tlon,$Weight,$FromDate,$ToDate,$carrier_id,$rad)
    {
        $R = 6371;  //Earth's Mean Radius
        $queryTrip =    "SELECT *, (        6371 *
                                            acos(
                                                cos( radians( $Flat ) ) *
                                                cos( radians( `travelling_from_latitude` ) ) *
                                                cos(
                                                    radians( `travelling_from_longitude` ) - radians( $Flon )
                                                ) +
                                                sin(radians($Flat)) *
                                                sin(radians(`travelling_from_latitude`))
                                            )
                                        ) `fromdistance`, 
                                        (   6371 *
                                            acos(
                                                cos( radians( $Tlat ) ) *
                                                cos( radians( `travelling_to_latitude` ) ) *
                                                cos(
                                                    radians( `travelling_to_longitude` ) - radians( $Tlon )
                                                ) +
                                                sin(radians($Tlat)) *
                                                sin(radians(`travelling_to_latitude`))
                                            )
                                        ) `todistance`
                                FROM `trips` as Trip
                                WHERE from_date = '$FromDate' 
                                    AND to_date = '$ToDate' 
                                    AND wait_will_carry = '$Weight'
                                    AND member_id = '$carrier_id'
                                    AND isBooked = '0'
                                    AND isActive = '1'
                                    AND isStatus = '1'
                                    AND isDelete = '0'";
                                //HAVING (`fromdistance` > $rad AND `todistance` > $rad)
                                //ORDER BY `fromdistance`";
        echo    $queryTrip;                 
        return $this->query($queryTrip);
    }
```

Which I used to call like this:-

```
$tripListArray = $this->Trip->getTripListMatchingItem($tripFromLat,$tripFromLong,$tripToLat,$tripToLong,$tripWeight,$tripStartDate,$tripEndDate,$carrier_id,400);
```

I was getting blank data. So I removed the condition of

```
//HAVING (`fromdistance` > $rad AND `todistance` > $rad)
//ORDER BY `fromdistance`";
```

I only check what `todistance` value i was getting.
The reason why my data was blank because `todistance` was coming null.

If the item `latitude and longitude` coincides accurately with trip `latitude & longitude` them the `fromdistance` & `todistance` both should come as zero.

Why am i getting `fromdistance` as **zero** and `todistance` as **NULL**?

[image]

Here's is the actual MySQL query which I echoed:

```
SELECT *, (
        6371 *
        acos(
            cos( radians( 15.2993265 ) ) *
            cos( radians( `travelling_from_latitude` ) ) *
            cos(
                radians( `travelling_from_longitude` ) - radians( 74.12399599999999 )
            ) +
            sin(radians(15.2993265)) *
            sin(radians(`travelling_from_latitude`))
            )
        ) `fromdistance`, (
                    6371 *
                    acos(
                        cos( radians( 10.8505159 ) ) *
                        cos( radians( `travelling_to_latitude` ) ) *
                        cos(
                            radians( `travelling_to_longitude` ) - radians( 76.2710833 )
                        ) +
                        sin(radians(10.8505159)) *
                        sin(radians(`travelling_to_latitude`))
                    )
                ) `todistance`
        FROM `trips` as Trip
        WHERE from_date = '2016-07-27' 
        AND to_date = '2016-07-30' 
        AND wait_will_carry = '4'
        AND member_id = '13'
        AND isBooked = '0'
        AND isActive = '1'
        AND isStatus = '1'
        AND isDelete = '0'
```

Comment: Your column is called `traveling_from_latitude` (one el, "l") while your formula uses `travelling_from_longitude` (two els, "ll").

Comment: It depends on what is the default value of this column in your table structure

Comment: @bishop that was just a typo while writing the question.